# WCF message security stopped working after server certificate changed

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Our Server/Service certificate expired and we issued a new one. Replaced it at the certificate store (works as SSL server certificate without issues), set access right for AppPoolIdentity under which the service is running to it's private key.
My Service Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="A2AValidation" type="SPOZUS_T2S_A2A.A2AValidation+CustomBehaviorSection, SPOZUS_T2S_A2A, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
  <add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MessageSecurityBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="true" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ClientSecBehavior" name="SPOZUS_T2S_A2A.Service">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="A2AValidationBehavior" bindingNamespace="https://DRW2012IIS.XXX.XXXX.XX:10002/A2A" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageSecurityBinding" name="A2AmessageEndpoint" contract="SPOZUS_T2S_A2A.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="A2AMessageEndpointMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://DRW2012IIS.XXX.XXXX.XX:10002/A2A/" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="A2AValidationBehavior">
      <A2AValidation />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientSecBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="DRW2012IIS.XXX.XXXX.XX" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

When I access the service from browser it's throwing error:

```
[CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.
]
   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer) +5273481
   System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle) +94
   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair() +136
   System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize) +203
   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey() +240
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.GetKeyContainerInfo(X509Certificate2 certificate) +42
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.CanKeyDoKeyExchange(X509Certificate2 certificate) +10
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.EnsureCertificateCanDoKeyExchange(X509Certificate2 certificate) +64

[ArgumentException: It is likely that certificate 'CN=DRW2012IIS.XXX.XXXX.XX, OU=IT, O=XXXXX, L=XXXXX, S=XXXX, C=XX' may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail.]
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.EnsureCertificateCanDoKeyExchange(X509Certificate2 certificate) +336
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateServerX509TokenProvider() +35
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateLocalSecurityTokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement) +64
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenProvider(SecurityTokenRequirement requirement) +59
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoServerX509TokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement) +261
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoSecurityTokenAuthenticator(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement recipientRequirement, Boolean requireClientCertificate, SecurityTokenResolver& sctResolver) +829
   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement tokenRequirement, SecurityTokenResolver& outOfBandTokenResolver) +709
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocolFactory.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +208
   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +21
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +81
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +221
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +73
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +130
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenAuthenticator.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +130
   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +21
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenAuthenticator.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +16
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +842
   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +21
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +125
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +221
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +73
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +130
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +347
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +130
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +738

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/TEST/A2A/Service.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: It is likely that certificate 'CN=DRW2012IIS.XXX.XXXX.XX, OU=IT, O=XXXXX, L=XXXXX, S=XXXX, C=XX' may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key. Please see inner exception for detail..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +604003
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +238
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +178
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with uppercase subject name used in the certificate subject name. I've reissued the certificate with lowercase domain specification and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact error message as well and spent quite a while narrowing down the issues. We were using [Octopus Deploy](http://www.octopus.com) to install our PFX certificates, with the Tentacle running as LocalSystem.

There were a few interesting findings:

1. Oddly enough, it turned out that LocalSystem did not have sufficient permissions to install the private key to the right folder (usually *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys*). The Certificates snap-in in the Management Console (mmc.exe) it showed the usual *"You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate"* message. I'm not sure if this is the usual setup or company policy.
2. There was no error from the Tentacle during installation. It's possible an error was generated but swallowed. Perhaps Octopus support can help with this.
3. The Octopus Tentacle does not re-install the certificate if it was already present, which hid the problem for a while as we'd originally installed them manually.
4. The account installing the certificates needs write permissions to that folder, while the account using them needs read permissions. Ensuring the permissions were correct solved the issue for us.